# how to improve the accuracy of radius in ClCircularRegion in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location, geofencing

I am implementing geofencing within some regions. I was testing my application using the simulator. I have two different regions that have a center at the following coordinates:`28.698000` latitude, `77.140800` longitude and another with the coordinates `28.707646` latitude, `77.125775` longitude. However, when I use the iPhone simulator and try to enter one of the regions, I happen to enter both regions instead of just one region, even though I set the radius to 100m. 
**how can i improve the accuracy ?**
i have the below code in my `viewDidLoad` method

```
manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.delegate = self
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

are the results inaccurate because i am testing them on a simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

There's two things that I would fix. The first one is indeed the fact that you are using a simulator. Try on a mobile device, and turn the GPS/location on. Secondly, are you testing indoors? According to our experiences, while using GPS indoors, the location is always about 15-30m off, usually showing that you'd be located somewhere outside on the street a bit down the road.